# Only the text shows in rendered view

Tags: rendering

So I've been having this problem in Blender 2.79. Every time I go to the rendered view. This happens:

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Hello,please give more info : share your whole screen

Comment: or even better...show us your blend file

Answer (score 1):

With no further information there could be two main reasons:

1. If the object is visible in the Viewport, but invisible in the rendered image, you've set *Disable in Renders* for the object.
2. If it's already invisible in 3D Viewport when you set the mode *Viewport* > *Rendered* (as your question sounds like), you probably disabled Camera Visibility under *Properties* > *Object* > *Cycles Settings* > *Ray Visibility*

[image: Object Visibility]